# Clicking 'New item' on any SP2013 list takes me to homepage instead of Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

On any List I create on my site (Custom List, Announcements, Promoted Links etc) whenever I click 'new item' I am redirected to my site homepage, rather than the form.

I can enter items ok via 'Quick Edit' then if I try to edit one of those items, again I am returned to the homepage.

I've tried customising a List with InfoPath, same things happens.  I then change back to the SharePoint form (via List Settings > Form Settings) and still the same.

If I try to link to 'New item' via sites/sitename/List/listname/newform.aspx again I am returned to the site homepage.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Since created a sub-site off of this site and that has the same problem too, so it points to something in the site collections features.  Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) might be worth a try:

- Go to Site Settings -> Manage site features
- Find "Minimal Download Strategy" and click Deactivate

MDS can cause some hairy problems on sites with custom code or custom master pages, as explained [here](http://www.threewill.com/working-with-and-around-sharepoint-2013s-minimal-download-strategy/), and I think it is turned on by default.  Let me know if this helps!

Comment: No, that didn't work - but thank you for the suggestion anyway